# Closing a question that wasn't ever really a problem?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I ran across this question in the close queue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004540/how-to-find-out-what-is-making-mysql-process-run-long. The user describes a problem with a process hanging around for too long that is apparently a daemon process. So essentially the user assumed there was a problem even though no problem exists. I'm not really sure whether this is a candidate for a close, but I imagine it happens more often than just here. (For example, I've run across a few questions where the code posted in the question did exactly what the asker wanted.) Should questions where the situation the asker presents is actually normal, expected behavior that in no way needs addressing be closed? If so, what close reason? "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error," seems tempting and somewhat in the spirit of the situation, but it doesn't seem to exactly fit since the situation here does indeed still exist and can be reproduced (by letting the database server run for while).

I considered the possibility this had been asked before, but with the fairly recent revamping of close reasons, I figured the answer might be different now; I also didn't find a duplicate.

Comment: Closing is one thing, but who is the dumbass who deleted [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004540/how-to-find-out-what-is-making-mysql-process-run-long)? It should have been left up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two different types of questions that must be distinguished.

---

First are the ones "where the code posted in the question did exactly what the asker wanted". Those are prime candidates to be closed for the off-topic reason that states,

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

You could also close them as "unclear", but mostly because that is a vague, catch-all category. I prefer to be more specific when one of the other reasons fits.

The reason you close these questions is because they are unlikely to ever be useful to anyone in the future. If the code works perfectly well, no one else is going to be having the same "problem", and it's hard to imagine a useful answer.

The only answer that *might* be useful would be one that commented on larger problems of design/practice with the code. But we already have a site for that, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

---

Second are questions like [the one you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004540/how-to-find-out-what-is-making-mysql-process-run-long). To experts, this might be a "duh" question, but that doesn't (necessarily) make it a *bad* question. It is reasonable for others to have the same question in the future, and it is possible to write a detailed answer that would be useful for those other people in the same situation.

In fact, that particular question is phrased almost perfectly for this. It says:

> How does one trace back to the original cause/query doing this? or is it normal?

You say that it is normal, that there is no real problem, it is just a misunderstanding on the part of the asker. Great--that would be your answer! There is nothing wrong with answering a question simply with "No, this is quite normal because…" or "No, you don't need to worry about that because…" or "No, that is not possible because…". You do need the "because" part, of course, but anyone qualified to post such an answer already knows why.

The perfect answer could even go on to explain how you know this to be true, and how someone could go above investigating this in the future. How do you trace it back to the original cause? etc. The asker here sets this up nicely, allowing you to be general and help even more people.

So although I am not an expert in *any* of the questions' tags, I don't think this question needs to be closed. Improved, perhaps. But not closed. There is an educational opportunity awaiting.

Comment: Except there isn't an educational opportunity, because [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004540/how-to-find-out-what-is-making-mysql-process-run-long) got deleted, which is wrong.